# floating TOC in tufte book

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, bookdown, tufte

I am trying to do something simple: render the tufte options for a book using the basic bookdown example package. I can make the tufte style book fine, but I want it to have the floating TOC and not the TOC at the top

Following the Definitive Guide bookdown book suggests a modification to the toc specifications. I'm using the stock bookdown-demo-master download.

This yaml makes the example in tufte format, but with an unattractive and not usable header with the toc:

```
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  tufte::tufte_html: default
  tufte::tufte_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
  bookdown::tufte_html_book:
    toc: true
    css: toc.css
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
---
```

But adding the float option:

```
  bookdown::tufte_html_book:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    css: toc.css
```

gives an error:

```
Error in rmarkdown::html_document(..., extra_dependencies = c(extra_dependencies,  : 
  You must use a theme when specifying the 'toc_float' option
Calls: <Anonymous> ... html_chapters -> base_format -> html_document2 -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I don't see that the need to include a theme is written in the "Definitive Guide" book. In any case, addition of a theme in the normal way doesn't help. Surely this is doable and I'm just missing something fundamental.

For the record, this question was [also posted to the Github repository](https://github.com/rstudio/tufte/issues/72) of the **tufte** package.